# Jquery script error "Access is denied"

Tags: javascript, jquery, access-denied

I have a script in which I am trying to open a child window and disable a parent window and re-enable the parent once the child window is closed as shown below:

```
function OpenChild() {
lockOpportunity();
if (ClinicalDataWindow == null || ClinicalDataWindow.closed) {
    ClinicalDataWindow = window.open(clinicalDataUrl, 'EditOppClinicalData',   GetWindowOptions(1020, 600), true);
    var unloadFunc = function () { unlockOpportunity(); };
    if (ClinicalDataWindow) {     
        if (ClinicalDataWindow.addEventListener) {
            ClinicalDataWindow.addEventListener('unload', unloadFunc, false);
        }
        else {
            ClinicalDataWindow.attachEvent('onunload', unloadFunc); 
        }
             }
        }
else {
    ClinicalDataWindow.focus();
}
return false;
}


function lockOpportunity() {
$('#overlay').addClass('locking-overlay');
$('#overlay').height($(".t-edit-form-container").height());
$('#overlay').show();
}
function unlockOpportunity() {
$('#overlay').removeClass('locking-overlay');
$('#overlay').hide();
}
```

Below is the div which i am converting to an overlay to lock the parent

```
<div id="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
   .locking-overlay      
         {
            position: absolute;      
            width:930px;     
            @*height: 700px;*@
            z-index: 1000; 
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        }
```

Every works perfectly on my local machine. BUt when I run this code on the server I am getting Script error "Access is denied" error. The child window is in the same domain and I am using IIS7.

**EDIT:**  The script code is in an external js file.

Comment: You forgot a `)` on line 4 of your JS.

Comment: on which browser are you running the code?

Comment: Line 5 is continuation of Line 4

Comment: Change the security setting in IE. you can google around on how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your clinicalDataUrl follow the Same Origin Policy?
Which means you can open a new window on whichever url you want but to interact with it you need to be in the same domain, protocol and port from where you try to interact.

EDIT: here is what i mean in my 2nd comment

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('unlockOpportunityEvent',unlockOpportunity);

});

function OpenChild() {
lockOpportunity();
var origin = window;
if (ClinicalDataWindow == null || ClinicalDataWindow.closed) {
    ClinicalDataWindow = window.open(clinicalDataUrl, 'EditOppClinicalData',   GetWindowOptions(1020, 600), true);
    var unloadFunc = function () { $(origin).trigger('unlockOpportunityEvent'); };
    if (ClinicalDataWindow) {     
        if (ClinicalDataWindow.addEventListener) {
            ClinicalDataWindow.addEventListener('unload', unloadFunc, false);
        }
        else {
            ClinicalDataWindow.attachEvent('onunload', unloadFunc); 
        }
             }
        }
else {
    ClinicalDataWindow.focus();
}
return false;
}


function lockOpportunity() {
$('#overlay').addClass('locking-overlay');
$('#overlay').height($(".t-edit-form-container").height());
$('#overlay').show();
}
function unlockOpportunity() {
$('#overlay').removeClass('locking-overlay');
$('#overlay').hide();
}
```

Comment: yes.. its in the same domain... it follows Same Origin Policy... The script doesnt give me any error on my local machine.... I get this error after deploying the code

Comment: maybe it's you filesystem then. Is it your resource fetching that throws a Access is Denied? I mean maybe your server configuration is not the same or the file r/w not good

Comment: I use that js file for other purpose also and everything else works fine

Comment: aaah i got it, you add function on event that works in another window. jQuery has trouble with that imo, you should try triggering events from a window to another instead of passing function as arguments.

Comment: yeah that's weird, if you try with a real navigator? like Chrome or FF with console on. the error should be more explicit. Also you are refering to jQuery inside the event you attach to the window created, does it have jQuery loaded in the new window?

Comment: Nice explanation, But let me give it a shot and see if the above code works.. I am restricted from Using any browser other than IE so I can't check with FF or G Chrome.